# Problem transferring files from old 2008 iMac to new 2015 iMac using Migration assistant

Tags: imac

Transferring files from old 2008 iMac to new 2015 iMac using Migration assistant and ethernet cable - work fine, albeit 3 hours, until says " About 12 minutes remaining" on the new iMac and About 16 minutes remaining on old iMac, seems to have frozen for last 2.5 hours, ideas?

Comment: You haven't mentioned or tagged the source (2008 iMac) and target (2015 iMac) OS X versions. You might see if this [update to Migration Assistant](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1434?locale=en_US) is appropriate for your situation. If you can do it, a Time Machine backup from an external HD can be used in Migration Assistant, too.

Answer (score 1):

Failed hard drive? Select your Apple Menu, hold down the alt/option key, and choose "System Information". Navigate to "Storage". Check the field reading "S.M.A.R.T. Status". It should read "Verified" if OS X thinks everything is OK.

[image: Screenshot of System Information, Storage item]